# Search icon on mobile site unresponsive and no longer toggles open

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

The search icon on my mobile website suddenly stopped working recently. It's supposed to toggle open a search bar; however, now when I click it, nothing happens.

When I long press via Chrome on mobile it displays "about:blank#blocked" and on Firefox on hover it displays javascript:void(0).

Not sure what caused it to stop working and it's a bit frustrating.

If anyone has any insights or ideas on how to solve it, that would be super helpful.

My website is [www.gentlemanwithin.com](http://www.gentlemanwithin.com)

Comment: `My website is` not a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - `about:blank#blocked` sounds like Chrome thinks your website is worthy of being blocked

Answer (score 0):

I see your issue:-
Your issue is when you are trying to access custom search form that unable to access because you added an extra search button which is not belongs to that. So you try toggle function to show yellow colored area of your code. After it your issue will solve. Below I have attached your site screenshot image, that you can see it for the reference.

[image: Reference Image for your issue fixation.]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I follow the first part in that there's an extra search button, I'm not quite clear on the action steps to take in order to resolve the issue. Is there a specific piece of code that's necessary to be removed or added in order to restore the search icon to toggle open? Thanks again.